# OnCheckedChanged event not firing when Checkboxes within Repeater are checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I am a relatively new developer, and have only been doing this for about 6 months full time, so thank you in advance for reading and/or responding to my question

I have a databound repeater. Inside this repeater, I have a gridview, SQLDS, and 2 checkboxes. Both checkboxes have a OnCheckedChanged event and AutoPostback is set to true. The repeater has an OnItemDataBound event as well.

Here is a sample of how my code is laid out:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Panel>
                <asp:UpdatePanel>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Checkbox ID="Checkbox1" Autopostback="True" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged">
                        <asp:Checkbox ID="Checkbox2"Autopostback="True" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox2_CheckedChanged">
                        <asp:Gridview ID="Gridview1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                        <asp:SQLDataSource ID="SQLDataSource1" SelectCommand="SP1" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </asp:Panel>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

And the C#

```
    protected void Checkbox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Checkbox1.Checked == true)
            {
                if (Checkbox2.Checked == true)
                    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SP1";
                else
                    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SP2";
            }
            else
                SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SP3";
    }
    protected void Checkbox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Checkbox2.Checked == true)
            {
                if (Checkbox1.Checked == true)
                    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SP3";
                else
                    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SP2";
            }
            else
                SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SP1";
    }

    protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        //Uses FindControl to Databind the GV and hides it if GV.Rows.Count==0
    }
```

I'm doing all of this within an AJAX TabPanel. I have another page where this code works perfectly, but it's not inside a repeater on that other page.

Essentially, I have a page load with a gridview, and the two checkboxes change what SP fills the gridview. The problem I'm having is that when you uncheck the checkbox (they start checked), it 1. Just rechecks itself and 2. Doesn't hit the CheckedChanged event.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: I don't see the checkboxes linked to the eventhandlers and autpostback set to true. Can you show where you are doing this?

Comment: Yes, sorry. They're set as such in the ASP tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Autopostback on the checkboxes is causing the SQLDatasource to just revert to the original Stored Procedure, as it hits page load and just ignores the oncheckchanged events.

What I did is I took all of my databinding events in pageload and put them inside of a `if (!IsPostBack)` clause, so that when the Autopostback hits, it doesn't rebind the SQLDS to the original value.

This way, when the autopostback occurs, there's nothing for it to do, and it hits the OnCheckedChanged events as it's supposed to.

Thank you everyone for reading and responding.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `AutoPostBack=True` attribute for the checkboxes and also register/assign event handlers of all controls which are added into the UpdatePanel through `Triggers` property of UpdatePanel control.

Comment: I did just that, set `AutoPostBack=True` as well as set up Triggers on the UpdatePanel in the form of `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Checkbox1" EventName="CheckedChanged" />` and `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Checkbox2" EventName="CheckedChanged" />` - The issue remains with the checkboxes not hitting their checkedchanged events.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Repeater has an event that causes a round trip from client to occur. The event is called ItemCommand. Check out this link :- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand.aspx

Hope this helps

Comment: This looks like it would be useful, but I'm not sure how to implement it. The `OnCheckedChanged` events need their own methods, so I'm not sure what to put inside a `Repeater1_ItemCommand`  method.

Answer (score 1):

i found a similar issue and solved

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/88960/OnCheckedChanged-Event-for-the-checkbox-inside-the/?cmt=3621

Regards

Comment: I saw that link as well, and tried implementing it. It doesn't solve the "re-check an unchecked link" problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to bring the `UpdatePanel` outside of the repeater, and add `runat="server"`. You should also bring the datasource control outside of the repeater too, and reuse it for all of the GridViews inside of the repeater.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <!-- checkboxes -->
                <!-- gridview -->
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ...>
```

Comment: @RockiesMagicNumber: Please see my answer. I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Actually your databinding method probably called outside the if(!ISPOSTBACK) { }
condition, so call this method inside the ispostback block, i hope your problem will be solved.